# How to stop TTS software from waking me up at night

Tags: windows-10, accessibility, narrator, tts

I am vision impaired and I have NVDA installed on my Windows 10 PC. Last night (after midnight), when Windows decided to auto-update (and reboot) itself, the PC started announcing its progress aloud ("Updating Windows, please don't turn off you computer, 1%, 5%, 10%", etc). I don't know if it was NVDA talking, or Microsoft Narrator. Today I double-checked that both NVDA and Microsoft Narrator have "Autostart after login" and "Autostart before login" disabled. Am I missing some other option that I need to touch?

Comment: If your speakers are separate from your computer, you may want to consider to turn them off, optionally buying external speakers and turn off the internal ones.

Comment: Another option is to stick a 3.5mm jack connector in the PC. It doesn't have to be connected to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enable
[Focus assist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/focus-assist-automatic-activation-settings-81ed1b25-809b-741d-549c-7696474d15d3)
(also called quiet hours in earlier versions of Windows 10),
described as :

> allows you to avoid distracting notifications when you need to stay focused. It's set by default to activate automatically when you're duplicating your display, playing a game, or using an app in full screen mode. You can control any or all of these, as well as determining to what level notifications are suppressed.

- Go to *Start  > Settings  > System > Focus assist*
- Set "Priority only"
  (see only notifications from a list you can customize to your liking),
  or "Alarms Only" (hide everything except alarms).
- Under Automatic rules, set "During these times" to On
- Click "During these times"
- Set the hours when you should not be disturbed.

Comment: Thanks! I did that now. Your quote says "avoid distracting notifications" and I don't think the "Updating Windows, please don't turn off you computer" blue screen counts as a notification. But maybe it does - let's see! :)